# How doest the bitcoind command "move" work?

Tags: bitcoind

Officiall docs says about this command: "Move from one account in your wallet to another" [link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list)

Also from official docs: "Moves are not broadcast to the network, and never incur transaction fees; they just adjust account balances in the wallet." [link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained)

As I understand - account is a list of private-public keys (and assosiated metadata)
So only action that we can do - move one or more key pairs from one account to another.
But in this case we have a problem - we could not move any arbitrary amount of BTC, but only the amount that already associated with addresses. Strange command...

So what does this command actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it refers to the accounts having a shared pool of money. When account A gets a deposit, the account gets a tally and it goes into the pool. When account B gets a deposit, the account gets a tally and it goes into the same pool. Moving money from A to B doesn't actually move the money address-wise, just changes the tallies. So if account A withdraws MORE than account A had deposited, part of that money will come from account B's deposit.

Comment: BTC tied with addresses. Therefore, if you send 1BTC to the address Z1 - everyone will see that Z1 has 1BTC. If you want to credit Z2 via BTC tied with Z1 – you need to make one more public transaction. |-|-| As I understand, “account balance” – is the sum of BTC, that tied with account’s addresses. So without new transactions “account balance” can have just discrete value. If you want to set to “account balance” some other value – you need to make new transaction.   (I can’t find where my logic is wrong, but it is so because "move" command works :)